Does human nature begin at conception?
If, for example, a human female is more likely to demonstrate the quality of nurturing over males.
Is this quality in females an innate quality at conception, or is it a societal role?
Although most characteristics are influenced by experience, it also seems to be the case that how a human reacts to experience is determined by a nature that exists already fully formed at the time of conception. Does this imply that the human identity as a person is also fully formed at conception? Note that it isn't an answer to say that the behavior of the person will evolve in the future, because that is always the case. That is, there is no time in a person's life save just before death when his or her behavior is fixed and unchanging; it is always evolving with experience, but if it is already determined at time T how the person will respond to experiences in the future, doesn't that mean that the person's nature is already fully formed at time T?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It depends on what you mean by human nature (SEP). Genetically, human nature begins at conception, because human nature must encompass all aspects of being genetically human and conception are those moments when the human organism comes into existence. Life traditionally is often ascribed to the quickening since without modern science, it's difficult to peer into the womb. Human nature is often spoken of as being man's natural state in a tacit nod to naturalism. It is often meant to speak of universals and long-observed norms among human beings in an anthropological sense. So, without being more specific it's tough to answer your question. From the SEP article:

Alongside such varying and frequently conflicting normative uses of the expression “human nature”, there are serious disagreements concerning the concept’s content and explanatory significance—the starkest being whether the expression “human nature” refers to anything at all. Some reasons given for saying there is no human nature are anthropological, grounded in views concerning the relationship between natural and cultural features of human life. Other reasons given are biological, deriving from the character of the human species as, like other species, an essentially historical product of evolution. Whether these reasons justify the claim that there is no human nature depends, at least in part, on what it is exactly that the expression is supposed to be picking out. Many contemporary proposals differ significantly in their answers to this question.

Therefore, given a lack of canonical definition, I would suggest that the term 'human nature' is an essentially contested concept. From WP:

In a paper delivered to the Aristotelian Society on 12 March 1956,1 Walter Bryce Gallie (1912–1998) introduced the term essentially contested concept to facilitate an understanding of the different applications or interpretations of the sorts of abstract, qualitative, and evaluative notions2—such as "art", "philanthropy",3 "power",4 and "social justice"—used in the domains of aesthetics, sustainable development, political philosophy, philosophy of history, and philosophy of religion.


Thank christ for your answer. I hope you voted to respect us as having some value. I'm humble and have no political agenda I'd prefer this contentious issue to be resolved with all parties satisfied and having no chips on anybodies shoulders

:D I upvoted the question because much of philosophy is wrangling over these broad terms. It's legitimate philosophical question to ask the question, but part of the philosophical method is honing our language, not to answer a broad question, but to decide what the next good question is. This is a good question, but it begs for a better one. Around here, broad questions tend to be rejected, so don't take it personally if it's closed.

@J.D That's good enough bollocks for me !!

@8Mad0Manc8 Neither is there such a thing as human nature (classic text on the matter), nor should epigenetics be ignored. The activation of genes (ie. essentially whether a particular protein is synthesised by a given cell or not) is very much dependent on interactions of the organism with the environment since it always depends on a stimulus. Deprive an organism of certain stimuli, or of building blocks for certain hormones, and the outcome will drastically change even with identical genes.
